# How many processes are created?

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I think that these creates 5 processes, but i need verification from you.
I am getting confused with this kind of questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    if (fork()){
        printf("A\n");
        exec("execjune");
    }
    else{
        printf("B\n");
        fork();
        fork();
        exec("execjune");
    }
    printf("D\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you think this creates 5 processes?  What about that reasoning do you have doubts about?

Comment: It will depend on what `execjune` does.

Comment: What happens when you run it?  What is the `execjune` program?  There isn't a standard C or POSIX function called `exec()` (the standard names all have 1-3 suffix letters, such as `execve()`); what does `exec()` do?

Comment: @ScottHunter fork() in if statement creates 1 child, so now we have 2 processes, one child and one parent right? Then we have another parent in else statement with 2 forks() so 1 parent and 2 childs if we add them 2 + 1 + 2 =  5

Comment: How many processes call the last `fork`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If the following program is executed, and if execjune executes the printf code ("C \ n"). I got this question from my profesor, so i need to ask that how many processes are created with these fork() statements.

Comment: @ScottHunter i think 1 but i am not sure about it

Comment: What does the "middle" `fork` do?

Comment: @ScottHunter creates another child process

Comment: When studying the behaviour of code like this, I find it helpful to add `printf()` calls that print the PID as well as salient information.  And call `fflush()` to ensure that output is generated as expected.  Create a function to encapsulate the work.  Without having run the code, and given that `exec()` is a variant of `execve()` and `execjune` prints “C”, I would expect to see A, B and five C’s in the output and no D’s.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler got it, thanks !

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why D i 0? I think that D is printed by main() method or ?

Comment: If the `exec()` function is a variant of `execve()` (and not a variant of `system()`), then both the `if` and `else` blocks replace the code shown with `execjune`, and there is no code path that prints D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

What happens when you run it? What is the `execjune` program? There isn't a standard C or POSIX function called `exec()` (the standard names all have 1-3 suffix letters, such as `execve()`); what does `exec()` do?

> If the following program is executed, and if `execjune` executes `printf("C\n")`. I got this question from my professor, so I need to ask how many processes are created with these `fork()` statements.

When studying the behaviour of code like this, I find it helpful to add `printf()` calls that print the PID as well as salient information. And call `fflush()` to ensure that output is generated as expected. Create a function to encapsulate the work. Without having run the code, and given that `exec()` is a variant of `execve()` and `execjune` prints “C”, I would expect to see A, B and five C’s in the output and no D’s.

> Why D is 0? I think that D is printed by `main()` method or …?

If the `exec()` function is a variant of `execve()` (and not a variant of `system()`), then both the `if` and `else` blocks replace the code shown with `execjune`, and there is no code path that prints D.

Here is some code.  Even on Linux (RHEL 7.4 tested), there is no function `exec()` under default compiler options with GCC 10.2.0.  So, I created a function `exec()`, and also a function `dbg_print()`, and used them with the code (source file `fork97.c` compiled to executable `fork97`):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void dbg_print(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    printf("%d: ", (int)getpid());
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fflush(stdout);
}

static inline void exec(const char *cmd)
{
    execl(cmd, (char *)0);
}

int main(void)
{
    dbg_print("Initial process\n");
    if (fork()){
    dbg_print("Parent process\n");
        printf("A\n");
        exec("execjune");
    }
    else{
    dbg_print("Child process\n");
        printf("B\n");
        fork();
    dbg_print("Between consecutive fork() calls\n");
        fork();
    dbg_print("After consecutive fork() calls\n");
        exec("execjune");
    }
    printf("D\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I also used program `execjune` created from source code `execjune.c` (which prints a PID as well as the letter C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d: C\n", (int)getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

And when I run the main program, I get output such as:

```
$ fork97
28876: Initial process
28876: Parent process
A
28877: Child process
B
28877: Between consecutive fork() calls
28877: After consecutive fork() calls
28879: After consecutive fork() calls
28878: Between consecutive fork() calls
28878: After consecutive fork() calls
28880: After consecutive fork() calls
28876: C
28879: C
$ 28880: C
28878: C
28877: C

$
```

Note that the prompt `$` before `28880` prints `C` is because there is no meaningful way to control that all the child processes exit before the parent process does (in part because the children all execute `execjune`).  The blank line and final `$` prompt comes from me hitting return after the last of the C lines.